# Swift: Returning a Boolean value

Tags: swift, boolean

I am creating a sort of tilling system that will take into account offers on certain products. I need to create a half price offer that will display either true or false depending whether the offer has been applied.

**HalfPrice Class:**

```
class HalfPriceOffer :Offer {

init(){
    super.init(name: "Half Price on Wine")
    applicableProducts = [901,902];
}

override func isApplicableToList(list: [ShoppingItem]) -> Bool {
    //should return true if a dicount can be applied based on the supplied list of products (i.e. a product must be matched to an offer)

    return false
}
```

**ShoppingItem Class**

```
import Foundation

class ShoppingItem {

var name :String
var priceInPence :Int
var productId :Int

init(name:String, price:Int, productId:Int){
    self.name = name
    self.priceInPence = price
    self.productId = productId
}
}
```

I know it uses loops; but I am unsure of how to actually write it. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So true if any `ShoppingItem` in `list` has a `productId` in `applicableProducts`?

Comment: Yes; basically if the productId in ShoppingItem is equal to the values in applicableProduct (901 and 902) then it would display true; and then false if not.

Comment: AND or OR is important. Is any match ok, or do all the products need to be there, or can `list` only contain items in the `applicableProducts` list (i.e. any other products in there means return false)?

Comment: The `list` can only contain the products in `applicableProducts` and will display true. With the the rest of the items just displaying false.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the reduce function to achieve this:

```
func isApplicableToList(list: [ShoppingItem]) -> Bool {
    return list.reduce(false) { (initial: Bool, current: ShoppingItem) -> Bool in
        return initial || applicableProducts.contains(current.productId)
    }
}
```

You can even write this shorter (Swift is awesome):

```
func isApplicableToList(list: [ShoppingItem]) -> Bool {
    return list.reduce(false) { $0 || applicableProducts.contains($1.productId) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's perhaps less complex to think whether the offer items are in the list rather than the list items are in the offer.

```
override func isApplicableToList(list: [ShoppingItem]) -> Bool {
    //should return true if a discount can be applied based on the supplied list of products (i.e. a product must be matched to an offer)
    let a = list.map({$0.productId})
    for p in applicableProducts
    {
        if !a.contains(p) {return false}
    }
    return true
}
```

And here's a full working code example, which fills in the implied gaps in the sample code:

```
class ShoppingItem {
    var name: String
    var priceInPence: Int
    var productId: Int

    init(name:String, price:Int, productId:Int){
        self.name = name
        self.priceInPence = price
        self.productId = productId
    }
}

class Offer {
    var applicableProducts = [Int]()
    var name:String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name

    }
    func isApplicableToList(list: [ShoppingItem]) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}


class HalfPriceOffer: Offer {
    init(){
        super.init(name: "Half Price on Wine")
        applicableProducts = [901,902]
    }

    override func isApplicableToList(list: [ShoppingItem]) -> Bool {
        //should return true if a discount can be applied based on the supplied list of products (i.e. a product must be matched to an offer)
        let a = list.map({$0.productId})
        for p in applicableProducts
        {
            if !a.contains(p) {return false}
        }
        return true
    }
}

let a = [ShoppingItem(name: "one", price: 1000, productId: 901), ShoppingItem(name: "two", price: 1009, productId: 907),ShoppingItem(name: "three", price: 1084, productId: 902)]
HalfPriceOffer().isApplicableToList(a) // true

let b = [ShoppingItem(name: "one", price: 1000, productId: 901), ShoppingItem(name: "two", price: 1009, productId: 907)]
HalfPriceOffer().isApplicableToList(b) // false
```